# Python - Error 34, Result too large

Tags: python

Estou tentando obter uma sequência de uma função recursiva, mas sempre me retorna o erro de overflow.

```py
import math

f = 1.5;
a = 100;
b = 10;
d = 1;
w = 3.76;

x1 = 0;
y1 = 0;
z1 = 0;

h = 10^-3;

for i in range (20000):
    x1 = (1/6)*h**3*y1*b-(1/2)*h**3*y1*a*x1**2-(1/6)*h**3*d*b*x1+(1/6)*h**3*d**2*y1+(1/6)*h**3*d*a*x1**3-(1/6)*h**3*d*f*math.cos(z1)-(1/6)*h**3*f*math.sin(z1)*w+(1/2)*h**2*b*x1-(1/2)*h**2*d*y1;-(1/2)*h**2*a*x1**3+(1/2)*h**2*f*math.cos(z1)+h*y1+x1;
    y1 = y1+h**3*y1*d*a*x1**2-(1/2)*h**3*a*x1**2*f*math.cos(z1)+(1/6)*h**3*w*d*f*math.sin(z1)+(1/6)*h**3*b**2*x1+(1/2)*h**3*a**2*x1**5-(1/6)*h**3*d**3*y1+(1/2)*h**2*y1*b+(1/2)*h**2*d**2*y1+h*b*x1-h*d*y1-h*a*x1**3+h*f*math.cos(z1)-h**3*a*x1*y1**2;-(1/3)*h**3*y1*d*b-(2/3)*h**3*b*a*x1**3+(1/6)*h**3*d**2*b*x1-(1/6)*h**3*d**2*a*x1**3-(3/2)*h**2*y1*a*x1**2;-(1/2)*h**2*d*b*x1+(1/2)*h**2*d*a*x1**3+(1/6)*h**3*b*f*math.cos(z1)+(1/6)*h**3*d**2*f*math.cos(z1)-(1/6)*h**3*f*math.cos(z1)*w**2;-(1/2)*h**2*d*f*math.cos(z1)-(1/2)*h**2*f*math.sin(z1)*w;
    z1 = h*w+z1;
```

Comment: Esse ocorre porque o resultado da sua operação matemática é maior do que o Python aguenta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por padrão, Python usa números em ponto flutuante de 64bit, que são os nativos da maioria das CPUs modernas.

Esses números são muito flexíveis, mas tem seus limites - e se alguma operação estourar para um número muito grande, ou muito pequeno, você vai ter um erro.

A linguagem também oferece o módulo `decimal` - que permite números decimais com precisão arbitrária (as operações são feitas em software) - vocẽ consegue configurar decimal.Decimal para prover a precisão que você precisa (há um `context` em que você seleciona a quantidade de casas decimais, por exemplo).

No entanto, a biblioteca decimals não tem as funções trigonométricas, que você está usando  -  é necessário usar uma biblioteca terceira para números grandes então.

Uma boa candidata é o ["mpmath"](http://mpmath.org/) - (pode ser instalado com `pip install mpmath`) - pra mim gerou fácil cos(0.5) com 500 casas decimais:

```
In [1]: import mpmath                                                                    

In [2]: mpmath.mp.dps = 500                                                              

In [3]: mpmath.cos(0.5)                                                                  
Out[3]: mpf('0.87758256189037271611628158260382965199164519710974405299761086831595076327421394740579418408468225835547840059310905399341382797683328026679975612095022401558762915687859072347693931098961673967701440899764912857021346821838454381839331616880754066081115940348983190805262434229367983882103953443260971069339648047544648581904315236807834735418729899796204210738598702695348232436617950049022784143745936541443062389248031244110265165332107358580108014739732581731402408144610066382413721269523135836227')
```